# .Net Core 2 - seed data and update through migrations

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, orm, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.1

Is there an option to seed data the first time and update the existing data the second time around if needed?
For instance we have a table that updates once a week/month/whatever
Is there a way to throw a new data as a seed that will preform some comparison and upon that rule decide if it's insert or update of existing row?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding
I've found only the insert for the first time option, but in real life application we need to be able to update the data dynamically as we go.

Comment: Seeding is not for continual updates. For continual updates, you'll need to create a worker service, likely.

Comment: That would be indeed the correct way to handle this. Possible easy way to handle this is by using Quartz. [Blog from Andrew Lock on using Quartz](https://andrewlock.net/creating-a-quartz-net-hosted-service-with-asp-net-core/) has a nice intro to this.